# Display div on a separate popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden div:

```
<div id="termSheetPrinted" style="visibility:hidden;">

</div>
```

that I am populating through the click of a button. After that population takes place, I would like to display the contents of this div on a separate popup window so the user can print it.

How would I do that with JQuery or Javascript or whatever is easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slandau,

**[edited]** as per new information in your comment below.

using the jquery dialog (you must reference the jquery-ui js), create a 2nd div on the base html page and call it something like termSheetPrintedDialog.

```
<div id="termSheetPrintedDialog" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

then in your document ready event, put:

```
$("#termSheetPrintedDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 510,
    width: 800,
    position: 'center',
    title: 'my snazzy popup window',
    },
    modal: true
});
```

then, in your button click event on your 1st modal form:

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function() {
    // your div population code here ... etc
    $('#termSheetPrintedDialog').html($('#termSheetPrinted').html());
    $('#termSheetPrintedDialog').dialog('open');
});
```

it's not pretty, but it's an approach based on the constraints that you have.

Comment: I could use a dialog but the button that is pressed to generate the div is actually also on a dialog...

Comment: slandau - you should change your question to reflect this fact, otherwise peeps will waste time on answers that will never be suitable!! i'll amend my answer to show you how

Comment: I'll try it out to see it it's suitable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var myWin = window.open('');                               
myWin.document.write(<html code>);
myWin.document.close();
```

Here is a link to read more about it:
[window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: This doesn't carry over any of my css stylings or jquery plugins from the web page though...